# Multiple Dropdown's with Submit Button

Tags: dropdown, categories

I am pulling 2 categories into 2 dropdown lists. When I click submit the URL is showing the filtering but its just loading the homepage. I want the user to be able to select multiple categories and submit to show results.

```
    <?php $price = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'show_option_none'   => 'Price Range:',
    'orderby'            => 'ID', 
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'hide_empty'         => 1, 
    'child_of'           => 110,
    'exclude'            => '',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1, 
    'name'               => 'price',
    'id'                 => '',
    'class'              => 'styled-select',
    'depth'              => 0,
    'tab_index'          => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false
    ); ?>

    <?php $region = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'show_option_none'   => 'Region:',
    'orderby'            => 'ID', 
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_count'         => 1,
    'hide_empty'         => 1, 
    'child_of'           => 32,
    'exclude'            => '',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'selected'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1, 
    'name'               => 'region',
    'id'                 => '',
    'class'              => 'styled-select',
    'depth'              => 0,
    'tab_index'          => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false
    ); ?>

    <div class="search">

    <form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="category" >

    <div class="four columns">
    <div class="search_drop"><?php wp_dropdown_categories( $price); ?> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
    <div class="search_drop"><?php wp_dropdown_categories( $region); ?> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" class="button" /></form>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All three of your dropdowns have the same name in the args so I'm guessing the last one is being used as the default. Give each one a unique name in the args and then use that name to pull the info from $_POST

Comment: Changing the 'name' in the args to something unique makes nothing work.

Comment: You will also need to change the name of the $_POST value you are trying to receive.  Did you change that value in your php page that handles the submission?  Just to test it, rename one of the dropdowns back to "cat" and you should see at least one of the responses.

Comment: Only seems to load the last dropdown.

Comment: That's what I expected.  Is that the one you renamed back to "cat"?  If so, can you post your code for where that gets handled?

Comment: Everything's in the code above. Theres nothing else.

Comment: There HAS to be more code somewhere that handles the submit action.  Is this page on a url that I can look at?  If not, can you paste the entire php page that the code above came from?

Comment: Yes, should it be loading the results on archive.php or search.php? This is where I'm not sure.
I have amended my code above. When I click filter the URL is showing filter results but its just the homepage loading.